# Keyboard mapping is incorrect until USB keyboard is plugged in

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I cant seem to find the solution or the cause to this problem. My keyboard mapping is incorrect at boot, ex / -> + or k -> 2

The mapping becomes correct after I plug in a USB keyboard (I am on a laptop), and stays that way when the keyboard is removed.

I have tried the following commands in an attempt to fix it, none makes any change:

```
modprobe atkbd reset=1
```

```
setxkbmap eu
```

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell \
    --object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
    --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
    "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
```

```
ibus engine xkb:us::eng
```

I have also checked all of the keyboard settings I can find, nothing changes when the keyboard is plugged in.

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.input-sources
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources false
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options @as []
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources per-window false
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current uint32 0
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources @a(ss) []
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources @a(ss) []
```

```
$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+us:2+inet(evdev)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,us
variant:    ,
```

I am totally out of ideas for this, and I feel like I have read every keyboard related post on the internet.

Comment: It seems like "Fn" key related functionality enabled/disabled. New laptops prefer Fn key to be enabled by default. Which means, as example, you cannot use F1-F12, keys until you press Fn. Might need to check BIOS/EFI for default setting.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Alex pointed me in the right  direction. My keyboard does not have a numlock key, and for some reason numlock breaks the keyboard layout.

```
sudo apt-get install numlockx
```

I then set the following command to run at startup.

```
numlockx off
```